A movie about small human faces taking over electronics
Okay, this one has been giving me a headache. I saw this movie a while ago, late 90s, early 00s maybe.
I do not remember the big story line but the main "thing" seemed to be those creatures that looked like human faces inside frames, one looked like a clock, another like a gear, there were a few more. At some point something happened to a guy and he got turned into one of these.
I also recall that those things could "take over" stuff like control panels and dials. Somewhere towards the end there was this huge board that looked like missile launch control and they started messing with it and it was a very bad thing or something.
Also there was a device that could "banish"(?) them. It was made by some crazy scientist guy. I recall a scene where he was pitching his device to someone else, using a lot of puns and wordplay to make acronyms out of the same letter. I actually saw it with a Russian dub, but the original English could be partially heard in the background. It was some kind of a "deporting" device as it was translated. As far as I remember it was barely used if at all.
